# Angularjs ui operations tend to be slow when there are more elements in a ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, user-interface, angularjs-filter

I have a application where more than two thousand records are loaded in to the scope and there is checkbox for every element. I have noticed that there is a huge delay between clicking and the input box getting selected. I have read that angular tends to be slow when the number of watches increase. Its not possible for me to have a paginate as i have implemented the search using angular filters and i need to search all the records at once. I know that the best way is to search in the sever and return the results. but for now is there any way to improve the performance even by a little bit.

```
<tr dir-paginate="document in archivedocuments| ArchiveDocumentViewFilter:documentView |ArchiveDocumentViewByChapterTagIdFilter:chapterTagId | orderBy:predicate:reverse|ArchiveDocumentsFilter:archiveDocumentsSearch| itemsPerPage: 10"
pagination-id="archiveDocsPag" ng-class="document.ProjectStatus != 3 ? '' : 'document-closed'">
<div cg-busy="{promise:archiveDocumentsPromise, templateUrl:'/app/modules/common/ui/fliploader/fliploader.html' ,backdrop:true, message:'Loading...'}">
    <td class="text-center table-header-link">
        <!-- Squared FOUR -->
        <div class="squaredFour">
            <input type="checkbox" value="None" name="checkboxfordocuments" ng-model="document.checked" ng-click="checkSingleArchiveDocument()"
            />
        </div>
    </td>
```

i have also added the my code as per the request archivedocuments can be more than 10,000
Thanks,

Comment: Please provide the code where you're executing that `ng-repeat` to find a possible solution

Comment: Why can't you have pagination? You can filter through all the items but display them by pages in the view. Although you can try using virtual scrolling technique and render only visible items + buffered on the edges.

Comment: i have also added the specific html. there are about 10 columns in that table and i only have added the checkbox coloumn thanks

Comment: @StanislavKvitash i use a pagination directive even though its used angular created watches for all the elements which is loaded in to the scope. Best way is to not load all the documents in to the scope which is not possible at this moment. ill look into virtual scrolling technique. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the watchers are created for all the elements? Probably the pagination directive itself  is not very good.